# How to map multiple properties under groupingBy property in java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get aggregate Marks of each student grouped by the department and sorted by their aggregate marks.
This is how I am trying.

### Student class properties:

```
private String firstName,lastName,branch,nationality,grade,shName;
private SubjectMarks subject;
private LocalDate dob;
```

### SubjectMarks class:

```
public SubjectMarks(int maths, int biology, int computers) {
    this.maths = maths;
    this.biology = biology;
    this.computers = computers;
}
public double getAverageMarks() {
    double avg = (getBiology() + getMaths() + getComputers())/3;
    return avg;
}
```

### Main class:

```
    Collections.sort(stList, new Comparator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student m1, Student m2) {
             if(m1.getSubject().getAverageMarks() == m2.getSubject().getAverageMarks()){
                    return 0;
                }
                return m1.getSubject().getAverageMarks()< m2.getSubject().getAverageMarks()? 1 : -1;
        }
    });

Map<String, List<Student>> groupSt=stList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getBranch,
        LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.toList()));


groupSt.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("\nBranch Name: " + k + "\n" + v.stream()
.flatMap(stud->Stream.of(stud.getFirstName(),stud.getSubject().getAverageMarks())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

updated code: This is how I am getting the output.

```
  Branch Name: ECE
  [Bob, 96.0, TOM, 84.33333333333333]

  Branch Name: CSE
  [Karthik, 94.33333333333333, Angelina, 91.0, Arun, 80.66666666666667]

  Branch Name: EEE
  [Meghan, 85.0]
```

This is the actual sorted order but Student objects are getting flattened in one line separated by a comma(,).

In the above output, since Bob got the highest aggregate marks of all branches, ECE comes first and followed by other branches sorted with student aggregate marks.

The Expected result is :
List of student names with their aggregate marks sorted.

```
  Branch Name: ECE
  [{Bob, 96.0},{TOM, 84.33333333333333}]

  Branch Name: CSE
  [{Karthik, 94.33333333333333}, {Angelina, 91.0}, {Arun, 
   80.66666666666667}]

  Branch Name: EEE
  [Meghan, 85.0]
```

Is there any way to map both name and average on `groupingBy` a property using streams?

Comment: What is the actual output when you run this code? It would be better to post that as well.

Comment: So the secret you don’t want to tell us, is that your code produces compiler errors?

Comment: Looking at the output, you don't really need an inner `List<Map<String, Double>`, overall`Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` should be sufficient for you. You can think around using a sorted map for the inner map there based on the comparator you desire.

Comment: @Gautham M sorry I couldn't respond to ur question because I was busy. Actually I have compilation errors for what I tried.

Comment: @Holger There are no secrets. I was a beginner in java. I hope it's better to give suggestions instead of breaking secrets. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
List<Student> stList = Arrays.asList(
        new Student("John", "Wall", "A", "a", "C", "sa", new SubjectMarks(65, 67, 100), LocalDate.now()),
        new Student("Arun", "Wall", "B", "a", "C", "sa", new SubjectMarks(45, 61, 95), LocalDate.now()),
        new Student("Marry", "Wall", "A", "a", "C", "sa", new SubjectMarks(90, 80, 92), LocalDate.now())
);
```

Idea:

1. `group` by "branch"
2. For each group (list) - `sort` by grade and `map` each student to a map of "name","grade".

Now it's easy to code:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Double>>> branchToSortedStudentsByGrade = stList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Student::getBranch, Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                l -> l.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(st -> st.getSubject().getAverageMarks(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                        .map(student -> Collections.singletonMap(student.getFirstName(), student.getSubject().getAverageMarks()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Output:

```
{
  A=[{Marry=87.0}, {John=77.0}],
  B=[{Arun=67.0}]
}
```

---

By the way:

Note that you divide by an integer in a floating-point context in `getAverageMarks`:

```
public double getAverageMarks() {
    double avg = (getBiology() + getMaths() + getComputers())/3;
    return avg;
}
```

This will cause all grades to be in this format- `xx.0`

If it's by mistake, I would recommend on this approach:

```
public double getAverageMarks() {
    return DoubleStream.of(maths, biology, computers)
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @MostNeededRabit. It is sorting the list of students. But, when I added John to branch C, Branch C should come first because Marry has highest aggregate marks with branch C. This is how I am getting the output :                                                         Branch Name: B
[{Arun=67.0}]

Branch Name: C
[{Marry=87.33333333333333}, {John=77.33333333333333}]                                    Expected is:
Branch Name: C
[{Marry=87.33333333333333}, {John=77.33333333333333}]         
Branch Name: B
[{Arun=67.0}]
Please check my output in the updated question.

Comment: @MostNeededRabit Thank you for the idea of using singletonMap(), this helped me a lot. I have modified some of my code and got the actual output.

Answer (score 4):

You could rather prefer to choose the return type to be a `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` or a custom class with appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` to ensure the uniqueness amongst the inner `List<Custom>`. I would frame the solution based on the former, and you can convert it to the one which is more readable to your actual code.

Once you have grouped each `branch` specific students, what you could do to ensure *firstName is mapped to maximum average marks* of that student is to perform a reduction using `toMap` with merge based on `Double::max`... **and then** collect these entries soted based on the marks (values).

Might look slightly complicated with the following code, but it could be broken into steps as well.

```
Map<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Double>> branchStudentsSortedOnMarks = stList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getBranch, // you got it!
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(Student::getFirstName,
                            s -> s.getSubject().getAverageMarks(), Double::max), // max average marks per name
                    map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue().reversed()) // sorted inn reverse based on value
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> b, LinkedHashMap::new)) 
            )));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Naman I tried yours this is cool. But it's sorting only the LinkedHashMap, I'm trying to sort the outer Map also. I mean the branch with the student who has the highest aggregate mark should come first followed by others. I think we can sort the list initially. Please check my output in the updated question. Thank again.

Comment: @Manmadh That would be yet another use case of sorting by value. Otherwise yes, you can sort the initial list based on max average marks too and collect the outer map in a `LinkedHashMap` while grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in your `Map<String, List<Map<String,Double>>>` the map inside the list would contain only one key-value pair. So I would suggest you to return `Map<String, List<Entry<String, Double>>>`. (`Entry` in `java.util.Map`)

Also, create a `getAverageMarks` in your student class which would return:

```java
return subject.getAverageMarks();
```

```java
// First define a function to sort based on average marks
UnaryOperator<List<Entry<String, Double>>> sort = 
    list -> {
        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()));
        return list;
    };

// function to create entry
Function<Student, Entry<String, Double>> getEntry = 
    s -> Map.entry(s.getFirstName(), s.getAverageMarks());

// return this
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Student::getBranch,        
        Collectors.mapping(getEntry, // map each student
                           // collect and apply sort as finisher
                           Collector.of(ArrayList::new,
                                        List::add,
                                        (x,y) -> {x.addAll(y); return x;},
                                        sort))));
```

Comment: Would be better to represent `Map<String, List<Entry<String, Double>>>`as `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`.

Comment: @Naman I initially thought of doing it the `Map<String, Map<String, Double>>` way with TreeMap being the inner map. But since `SortedMap`s takes a comparator which sorts on the `key` and not `value`, I thought of doing it this way. Is it possible to sort while collecting to a map? Or should it be done once the map is collected?

Comment: Mind that you can write `list.sort(comparator)` instead of `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` since Java 8.

Comment: @GauthamM In my understanding, unless you write a custom SortedMap implementation based on comparing values, you can't achieve that out of the box. That aside, my primary intention to comment on the return type was that the inner `List` allows duplicate entries based on the name, which would otherwise be the `key` of the inner map.

Comment: @Naman Yes got it now. I was actually not expecting multiple set of marks for the same person in the same branch.

Comment: @GauthamM Thank you. Got it how to do. This approach is also cool and working.